# Issue in iterating over Python dictionaries with lists and sub-dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing

I have a data structure I have read from a file which looks like below -

```
data = {"test":['[{"Day":"Monday","Device":"Android","Data":[1, 2, 3]}, {"Day":"Tuesday","Device":"Iphone","Data":[10, 20, 30]}]']}
```

I am trying to access the elements of the structure like below, peeling off one by one -

```
value = data["test"]
print(value)
#['[{"Day":"Monday","Device":"Android","Data":[1, 2, 3]}, {"Day":"Tuesday","Device":"Iphone","Data":[10, 20, 30]}]']

value1 = value[0]
print(value1)
#[{"Day":"Monday","Device":"Android","Data":[1, 2, 3]}, {"Day":"Tuesday","Device":"Iphone","Data":[10, 20, 30]}]


print(value1[0]) 
#I get only [ as if it is a string
```

Does the incoming structure has some problems, or am I accessing the wrong way.

Here is the link to reproduce - https://godbolt.org/

Comment: you need to parse your value as json too, as it's a string

Comment: `data['test']` is a list that contains exactly 1 JSON array. There are no lists or sub-dictionaries (yet); you need to decode the array first.

Comment: try `print(json.loads(value1)[0]) `

Comment: Using `print` obscures the fact that `value1` is a string, not a list, because the JSON and the Python string representations coincide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in JSON parser to convert this to a dictionary like so:

```
import json

for item in json.loads(data['test'][0]):
    print(item, type(item))

# >>> {'Day': 'Monday', 'Device': 'Android', 'Data': [1, 2, 3]} <class 'dict'>
# >>> {'Day': 'Tuesday', 'Device': 'Iphone', 'Data': [10, 20, 30]} <class 'dict'>
```

Note: printing `type(item)` is just to demonstrate that they're being converted to `dict` appropriately

Comment: It's more likely this is JSON that happens to be a valid Python expression, rather than an intentional Python expression.

Comment: if the inside is json, literal_eval will fail

Comment: Yeah, I'm rewriting this to use `json.loads`